# Unable to get value of JsonResult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the value of a JsonResult value returned by MVC to do some polling updates of a value, but I have been unable to get the actual values out of my JsonResult. I am new to jquery/JsonResult, so am probably overlooking something simple. I have reviewed the jquery documentation for $.each, and regular get/post information - so far none of my magical incantations have worked.

**The class value:**

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    public static bool isRunning { get; private set; }
    public static bool isConnected { get; private set; }
    public static int connectionCount { get; private set; }
    public static int channelMonitoredCount { get; private set; }
    public static List<string> channelList  { get; private set; }
    ...
```

**The initialization:**

```
public ConnectionManager()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        isConnected = false;
        connectionCount = 0;
        channelMonitoredCount = 0;
        channelList = new List<string>();
    }
```

**The GET - MVC:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetConnectionStatusPanel()
    {           
        var data = Json(new{Startup.CoreServicesManager});
        return data;
    }
```

**The Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetConnectionStatusPanel',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                alert("Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**The Expected Output:**

```
Key: isRunning, true
Key: isConnected, false
Key: connectionCount, 0
... etc
```

**The Actual Output:**

```
Key: CoreServicesManager, Value: [object Object]
```

So... what am I missing? I wanted to add the tag 'vNext' as it might be relevant. I'm using VS 14 - vNext MVC application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, in the connection manager class, the values should not have been static. Removing static resolved the issue.